# Всплывающей подсказки в jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем добрый день! Возник такой вопрос: как можно вызвать подсказку в jQuery.
Но суть в том, что бы сама подсказка выводилась в скрипте jQuery. Вот мой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

           $("#resultados").hide();
          $('#buscar_usuario').autocomplete( {
            source: 'ajax.php',
            select: function(event , ui){
                  $('#resultados').slideUp('slow', function(){
                        $('#resultados').html(
                            '<h2>Информация о пользователе<h2>' +
                            '<img src="'  + ui.item.foto + '"/>' +
                            '<strong>Пользователь: </strong>' + ui.item.value + '<br/>' +
                            '<strong>Количество предметов: </strong>' +'<a href=#  class="tooltip">' +  ui.item.descripcion +'<span class="tip">Проверка</span> '+'</a>'
                            );
                  });
                   $('#resultados').slideDown('slow');
              }
          });

 });
```

Мне нужно, что бы при на ведении на эту строчку выводилась подсказка:

```
<a href=#  class="tooltip">' +  ui.item.descripcion +'<span class="tip">Проверка</span> '+'</a>'
```

Как можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Использовать готовые решения в вашем случае не вариант? А то бы мог просто предложить один небольшой плагин для jQuery.

Comment: Может можно как то сделать место подсказки что бы модальное окно выводилось прни клике на эту сылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для динамически создаваемых элементов нужно использовать метод **live**. Вот пример кода, при наезде мышкой на ваш элемент (*на ссылку*) вылетает диалоговое окно.

```
$('.tooltip').live('mouseover', function() {alert('это предмет №тра-та-та');
});
```

Думаю, Вам не составит труда усовершенствовать его, чтобы вместо окна появлялась подсказка. :)

Comment: спасибо за помощь
Доработаю обязательно выложу пример...